# Serviços WCF com quantidade de métodos (endpoints) diferentes

Tags: .net, web-service, aplicação-web, wcf

Peguei um projeto que usa WCF e não estou conseguindo desvendar esse mistério.

Tenho duas solutions: ***Projeto A*** e ***Projeto B***. Quando ele tenta instanciar o `OAuthServiceClient` dentro do ***Projeto B***, ele gera o seguinte erro:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'SSOWebService.IOAuthService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

Código do ***Ambiente.ServiceModelClients.config***

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://sso.fundacao.interno/SSO/WebServices/OAuthService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IOAuthService"
            contract="OAuthService.IOAuthService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IOAuthService" />
</client>
```

Isso acontece, acredito eu, por diferença de quantidade de métodos do WCF do ***Projeto B*** (30 endpoints) e ***Projeto A*** (15 endpoints).

P.S. Ao analisar novamente o código percebo que há dentro do arquivo Reference.cs 5 construtores que não estão definidos dentro da interface

```
public interface IOAuthService {

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IOAuthService/IsValidToken", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IOAuthService/IsValidTokenResponse")]
    LoginResult IsValidToken(string token, string appClientID);

    // mais 29 outros métodos
        ....
    }
```

e ai na implementação existem 5 construtores, que consigo definir de onde estão sendo herdados

```
public partial class OAuthServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IOAuthService>, IOAuthService {

public OAuthServiceClient() {

}

public OAuthServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
        base(endpointConfigurationName) {
}

//... outros construtores

public LoginResult IsValidToken(string token, string appClientID) {
        return base.Channel.IsValidToken(token, appClientID);
}

//outros 29 métodos
....
```

Comment: não seria pela configuração do SSOWebService no appsetings ou appconfig ??

Comment: acredito que não seja, mas isso vai depender de qual configuração estamos falando.
De qualquer forma percebo que dentro das Referências do WCF (ambiente.ServicemodelClients.config,configuration.svcinfo,reference.cs) elas apontam para :
`<endpoint name="BasicHttpBinding_IOAuthService" ***contract="OAuthService.IOAuthService"*** bindingType="basicHttpBinding" address="http://siteDaEmpresa/SSO/WebServices/OAuthService.svc" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IOAuthService">`

Comment: E você não está chamando esse WS em algum a outra camanda diferente, onde esse endpoint não existe no config e o client não está sendo inicializado?

Comment: alguém poderia formatar o código por favor, tentei de várias maneiras mas não deu certo

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, acredito que já fiz a conferência de todas as referências , e todas apontam para o mesmo URL http://sso.fundacao.interno/SSO/WebServices/OAuthService.svc

Comment: A minha pergunta era: Se você utiliza ServiceModelClients no **ProjetoA** e ou no **ProjetoB**, a configuração do precisa ser feita no config deles também

Answer (score 0):

[image: Referência do Serviço]

Olá Acabei resolvendo o problema, simplesmente apagando e adicionando novamente as referências do serviço.